# iOS - Returning a variable from a block

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, alassetslibrary

I have an `iOS` project which is pulling images from a datasource method. I would like to be able to pull the image from the `assets library` (and the code chunk below does this just fine).

However, I need this `dataSource` method to return a `UIImage`, but when I use the assets library methods to get the image, the image is returned in a result block. Simply putting `return image` in the result block obviously does not work.

Does anyone have any idea how I can have the method return a `UIImage` from inside the result block? I have seen several other SO questions about returning images within blocks, but they are say to call another method. I - unfortunately - can't do that because this method is a [nimbus](http://nimbuskit.info) datasource method which must return a UIImage.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated! Code below:

```
- (UIImage *)photoAlbumScrollView: (NIPhotoAlbumScrollView *)photoAlbumScrollView
                     photoAtIndex: (NSInteger)photoIndex
                        photoSize: (NIPhotoScrollViewPhotoSize *)photoSize
                        isLoading: (BOOL *)isLoading
          originalPhotoDimensions: (CGSize *)originalPhotoDimensions {

    __block UIImage *image = nil;
    ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    [assetslibrary assetForURL:[_photos objectAtIndex:photoIndex]
                   resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset){
                       ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                       CGImageRef imageRef = [rep fullScreenImage];
                       if (imageRef) {
                           image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

                       }

                   }
                  failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                      //return nil;
                  }];

    return image;
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide more code as to how this dataSource method looks? The code you have above is obviously functional, but you say there is no way to message if from the dataSource - I have to believe I'm not the only person who has no clue what the true problem is at this point.

Comment: The returned image is always nil because the assetslibary call is asynchronous. So the return image is fired before the `resultBlock` is executed. And it appears to be illegal to place a `return image` in the `resultBlock` after the line `image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];`

Comment: I think you'll have to rework your architecture to load the images before querying your data source.

Answer (score 2):

You should create an array for each image. When this data source method Is first called, you will not have an image for that index in the array. Kick off the asset call then return a place holder image. When the block returns, replace the place holder image with the asset image returned in the block. You may need to perform this on the main queue using GCD.

Comment: You mean an array with a placeholder for each image, right? That's a good idea and gives good flexibility for how you handle your UI.

Comment: The array holds images returned from the block as a means of caching them. You do not need to store the placeholder image in the array. If the images are large, cashing them will take up significant memory, so you will want to skip this part of the process.

Comment: You may need to cache a thumbnail of the full sized image rather than the entire image if they are large. The loading parameter in the datasource method could indicate it is "aware" that you might not have the image at the time the method is called. As such, it may provide a mechanism for handling this scenario in another call, etc. To clarify, be sure to update the image on the main queue, as the code called in the block may not be on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I have a solution to your problem. The idea is to make use of a dispatch_group, since you can wait on a dispatch group - it gives you a way to block a thread until something happens. It may require that your datasource action NOT use the mainthread, but you are going to have to play with this. Lets assume that the object implementing photoAlbumScrollView is called 'obj'.

- obj creates a serial dispatch queue (called queue)
- datasource sends [obj photoAlbumScrollView] message
- photoAlbumScrollView does what it does now, but before returning waits on the queue
- the final block unblocks the queue letting the group finish

The code:

```
__block UIImage *image = nil;
ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myApp.assetFetch", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

[assetslibrary assetForURL:[_photos objectAtIndex:photoIndex]
               resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset){
                   ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                   CGImageRef imageRef = [rep fullScreenImage];
                   if (imageRef) {
                       image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
                   }
                   dispatch_resume(queue);
               }
              failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                   dispatch_resume(queue);
              }];
dispatch_suspend(queue);
dispatch_sync(queue, ^{ NSLog(@"UNSUSPEND!"); }); // ultimately a block with just a ';' in it
dispatch_release(queue);

return image;
```

I obviously did not test this but it or something close to it should work, assuming again that you can make this on a thread and not on the mainThread.

Comment: This is what I cannot do because that datasource method needs to return a UIImage. Am I missing something?